# posting to google sheets

Tags: javascript, php, google-sheets-api

I am trying to create a web form that will post data to my google sheet. I am finding that the only way to do this is to use OAuth2 where the client needs to authenticate with google. Is there a way that I can post to my own sheet without having to do the OAuth? I want to avoid having the google screen popup when trying to submit the form. Anyone know how to do this, without a hack? If it has to be done server-side, I am using PHP. Thanks

Comment: Please refer to the guide lines on [ask], as you don't show any code and don't show an actual *problem*

Comment: Please read the question, I don't have code to show, I am asking if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's *your* Google sheet that you are using for all visitors, then you only need to follow the flow once to obtain a refresh token and use a service account.  This obviously has to be done server-side, otherwise you expose your credentials to every visitor.

This guide [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) explains the process.

Comment: This is what I needed. Thanks